# (Python) 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 5: illegal multibyte sequence & [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Get error this error **"'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 5: illegal multibyte sequence"** ,when I try use this code :

```
        list_of_files2 = glob.glob('F:\\Project\\shiftly test\\Broadcom yield*.xls')  
        latest_file2 = max(list_of_files2, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

While change to this code , get this error  **[Errno 22] Invalid argument: "b'F:\\\\Project\\\\shiftly test\\Broadcom yield_2022-03-30.xls'"**

```
            list_of_files2 = glob.glob(rb'F:\\Project\\shiftly test\\Broadcom yield*.xls')  
           latest_file2 = max(list_of_files2, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

It seem like unable decoding the file properly .

Here the full code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
# while (True):
# for DIR in [DB_DIR]:
# if os.listdir(DIR) != []:
if os.path.exists(DB_DIR) != []:
    xmlfiles = os.listdir(DB_DIR)

    # Copy xls.file to another path
    list_of_files = glob.glob('F:\\Project\\shiftly test\\Broadcom yield*.xls')
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getmtime)


    print
    "latest %s" % (latest_file)

    with open('F:\\Project\\no_duplicate\\no_duplicate.txt','r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()

        print
        "read line %s" % (data)

    if latest_file != data:

        list_of_files2 = glob.glob(rb'F:\\Project\\shiftly test\\Broadcom yield*.xls')  ########################################## need change later
        latest_file2 = max(list_of_files2, key=os.path.getmtime)

        # time.sleep(10)

        try:
            statinfo = os.stat(latest_file2)

        except Exception as e :
            print (e)

        try:
            extratwword(latest_file2)
            with open('F:\\Project\\no_duplicate\\no_duplicate.txt','r+') as f:
                # convert to string:
                data = f.read()
                print
                "Done -- Writing & Executing: %s " % (data)
                f.seek(0)
                f.write(latest_file)
                f.truncate()

        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
```

Comment: None of the code you show should be reading file contents, only file names. Can you give the full traceback of the exception?

Comment: @Blckknght done insert a full  traceback of the exception

Comment: Um, the code isn't the same as a traceback. The traceback should say something like "Traceback (most recent call last):` followed by several lines showing the call stack that lead to where your exception occurred. But in the code you've shown, I can see you're suppressing exceptions in several places (with `try`/`except` blocks). You might want to remove those (at least temporarily) because if your exception is occurring in one of the `try` blocks, it will prevent the normal traceback from being printed (you'll only get the exception message, not the rest of the details).

Comment: @Blckknght  Actually the problem come from here " glob.glob('F:\\Project\\shiftly test\\Broadcom yield*.xls') " ,If I remove this code  then no more getting error. 
I had search through google and the solution is need insert " encoding='UTF-8' in the code , but I not sure how to insert by using python glob command.

Comment: How do you know that's where the trouble is? It doesn't make any sense for `glob` to be raising that exception. That's an exception related to reading the *contents* of files, but `glob` only deals with filenames. The fact that you only have a bare exception message is consistent with the `except Exception` lines you have suppressing the normal tracebacks from exceptions raised later on (e.g. from `data = f.read()`). Comment the exception handling out and you should find where the exception is *really* coming from.